# One-line copy command when source and dest path are the same

Tags: linux, backup, cp

I want to backup a file in some-other sub-directory different from my current directory like this:

```
cp /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eeee/file.sh /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eeee/file.sh.old
```

As you see both source and dest dir are the same, so common convention would be to change to the common directory, perform the copy im `./`, then change back to the original directory.

Is there a single-line command to accomplish the copy in this situation?

Comment: Is there a programming question in this?

Comment: If you cd in that path use can use "./"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Use this:

`cp /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eeee/{file.sh,file.sh.old}`

The curly braces will cause the first part of the string to be reused for each of the items separated by commas.  Bash is what expands the above into two separate paths and then passes it to `cp`.  To see what Bash would be passing to `cp`, simply add an `echo` to the beginning:

`echo cp /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eeee/{file.sh,file.sh.old}`

You will see that produces your original statement:

`cp /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eeee/file.sh /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eeee/file.sh.old`

You're just using a Bash trick to save on typing.

Comment: I should add, that for the specific example you gave, you could reuse the file name too: `cp /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eeee/file.sh{,.old}`  That will save you even more typing and also probably reduce the chance for typos since you could use tab completion to get to the original path.